# Web API 2 CORS pre flight Options request fails with 504 error

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API 2 project which needs to be accessed from a separate domain. GET requests work fine, but POST fails with the pre flight request. I can't get OPTIONS request to return correctly.

I have added the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors to the project.

In WebApiConfig.cs I call:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors();
```

My Web.config contains these values:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

In global.asax.cs I have added:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

In Fiddler I see a request to

> OPTIONS /api/app/controller HTTP/1.1

but the response is

> HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure

When AngularJS makes the request, it has these headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4104
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4104/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

If I use the Chrome plugin for Advanced REST Client with the same headers, it also fails. However, if I remove the header `Access-Control-Request-Method: POST`, I get a 200 response returned from the OPTIONS request.

---

Update:

After changing the Global.asax.cs code to

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
```

I get a 200 response code when making the request from Chrome Advanced REST client. However, I still see exactly the same timeout from the angular code calling the web api.

This is the AngularJs code:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.test.com/api/app/controller',
    data: postdata,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
.then(function(response) {
    // Do stuff
}, function() {
    // Show error
})
.finally(function() {
    // Cancel loading indicator
});
```

---

I have changed the first line of `Application_BeginRequest` to include logging:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log.Debug("Application_BeginRequest " + HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod);
```

For `GET` requests this logs `Application_BeginRequest GET`. Nothing is logged when the `OPTIONS` request is made from AngularJS. It looks like the code is `Application_BeginRequest` is never being reached. When I make the call from the same machine with Chrome Advanced REST API, it logs (and works correctly).

Comment: Are you using the Owin pipeline in your Web API?

Comment: Good problem!, this line (`<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />`)  in `web.config` is very important. You put it correctly, tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually add header by using Application_BeginRequest in Global.asax

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've updated my question with what I've implemented in global.asax. Sorry for missing from original question.

Comment: Accepting this answer. Another issue was masking that it was fixed, but this resolved the problem.